# What's the safest way to do electrical when forced to stand in water?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm working under a house and it isn't an option for a few reasons (time, equipment, etc) to drain the small 'pool' under it. Are rubber boots and gloves enough or is there other things I can do for safety?

Comment: The boots would (obviously?) have to be high enough to keep water from entering them, but as long as you prevent yourself from being a path to ground, you should be okay. Just make sure they're actually electrically insulated.

Comment: You're turning off the electricity to whatever you're working on, right?

Comment: Standing in water or on the moon, the safest way to do electrical work is without it energized. Possibly add in a snorkel if the water's deep.

Comment: The safest way for you to do electrical work when standing in water is to let somebody else be the one doing the electrical work while standing in the water.

Comment: I would like to point out you just described the number one cause of electrocution in the US. So remember there is no such thing as too safe.

Answer (score 7):

Turn off the breaker supplying the circuit you're working on. If there are many circuits, turn off the main breaker for the entire house. You may wish to lockout/tagout the breaker (box) for additional safety.

Answer (score 2):

### Turn the main breaker off / pull the meter

Do not mess with this. **It's very common** to de-energize a circuit only to find something else is energizing it.  That may be a multi-wire branch circuit, some sort of cross-wiring, inappropriately crossed neutrals, improper paralleling, ring circuits, you name it.

Comment: Well put, not to mention the breakers might be mis-marked or not properly ganged together, etc.  "It only takes a mistake of a split second to become dead forever."

Comment: When I  had to work on a factory (which also had water problems) I pulled the big 1000A knife switch which cut off the 480 feeding the transformers to both 120V panels.  I ran an extension cord from another service and was able to light up one circuit at a time.  Looking back at it, I can't believe I did *all that work* pretty much in the dark.